# RxJava retryWhen and onError

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

I am starting to developing using rxJava, and I have the following situation:

I have a observable and I want to have one subscriber to handle the error `onError`, and other subscriber to handle the `retryWhen`.

The retryWhen swallow the error, how avoid the error swallow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put `doOnError/doOnEach` before `retryWhen` like this:

```
    o.doOnError(t -> {
      // do something 
    }).retryWhen(o -> {
      // do something
    });
```